# Updating a subsection of a list with an "id" field

Tags: java, list, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to learn how to use the lambda functions for sleeker code but struggling to make this work.

I have two lists. The "old" list is always shorter or the same length as the "updated list".
I want to take the objects from the "updated list" and overwrite the "stale objects" in the shorter "old list".
The lists have a unique field for each object.

For example, it is a bit like updating books in a library with new editions. The UUID (title+author) remains the same but the new object replaces the old on the shelf with a new book/object.

I know I could do it the "long way" and make a `HashMap<MyUniqueFieldInMyObject, MyObject>` and then take the new `List<MyUpdatedObjects>` and do the same.

I.e. Have `HashMap<UniqueField, MyOldObject>` and  `HashMap<UniqueField, MyUpdatedObject>`, then iterate over the old objects with a pseudo "if updated objects have an entry with the same key, overwrite the value with the updated value"...

But...

Is there a "nicer" shorted way to do this with functional lambda statements?

I was thinking along the lines of:

```
List<MyObject> updatedList;
List<MyObject> oldList;

updatedList.forEach(MyObject -> {

    String id = MyObject.getId();

    if (oldList.stream().anyMatcher(MyObject -> 
        MyObject.getId().matches(id)) {
           //Do the replacement here? If so...how?
       }
}
```

Which is where I am lost!

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: What happens if the old list does not contain a new book? you want to add it to the old list?

Comment: No. I only want to update the ones currently in the old list.

Comment: Ok. If the book is in the old list is it definitely in the new list?

Comment: No. But I will remove the books in the old list that are not in the new list in a separate step.

I.e. It is like a book store supplier giving a large catalogue of their entire book warehouse but the library is only interested in updating the ones it currently has and that are available to be updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to update the list in place rather than making a new list, you can use [`List.replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-):

```
oldList.replaceAll(old -> 
    updateListe.stream()
        .filter(updated -> updated.getId().equals(old.getId())
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(old)
);
```

The main problem with this solution is that its complexity is O(size-of-old*size-of-updated).  The approach you described as "long way" can protect you from having to iterate over the entire updated list for every entry in the old list:

```
// note that this will throw if there are multiple entries with the same id
Map<String, MyObject> updatedMap = updatedList.stream()
                                         .collect(toMap(MyObject::getId, x->x));

oldList.replaceAll(old -> updatedMap.getOrDefault(old.getId(), old));
```

Comment: So basically, the syntactically longer way is actually the most and for the sake of say ~1000-10,000 entries on a mobile app the better option with updates in the sub Hz to maybe ~10ms?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to iterate over the `oldList` - the one you want to update. For each of the object iterated match the equivalent one by its `id` and replace it using `Stream::map`. If an object is not found, replace it with self (doesn't change the object) using `Optional::orElse`.

```
List<MyObject> newList = oldList
    .stream()                                                  // Change values with map()
    .map(old -> updatedList.stream()                           // Iterate each to find...
            .filter(updated -> old.getId() == updated.getId()) // ...by the same id
            .findFirst()                                       // Get new one to replace
            .orElse(old))                                      // Else keep the old one
    .collect(Collectors.toList());                             // Back to List
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Foo> updatedList = List.of(new Foo(1L, "new name", "new desc."));
List<Foo> oldList = List.of(new Foo(1L, "old name", "old desc."));

List<Foo> collect = Stream.concat(updatedList.stream(), oldList.stream())
            .collect(collectingAndThen(toMap(Foo::getId, identity(), Foo::merge), 
                     map -> new ArrayList(map.values())));

System.out.println(collect);
```

This will print out:
`[Foo{id=1, name='new name', details='old desc.'}]`

In `Foo::merge` you can define which fields need update:

```
class Foo {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String details;

    /*All args constructor*/
    /*getters*/

    public static Foo merge(Foo newFoo, Foo oldFoo) {
        return new Foo(oldFoo.id, newFoo.name, oldFoo.details);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best to add the objects to be updated into a new list to avoid changing a list you are streaming on and then you can simply replace the old with the new list

```
private List<MyObject> update(List<MyObject> updatedList, List<MyObject> oldList) {
    List<MyObject> newList = new ArrayList<>();

    updatedList.forEach(object -> {
        if (oldList.stream().anyMatch(old -> old.getUniqueId().equals(object.getUniqueId()))) {
            newList.add(object);
        }
    }

    return newList;
}
```